# Renaming the beginning of a file name in Python

Tags: python, file-rename

I am attempting to create an executable that renames all files in its folder.

I am lost on how to reference (and add to) the beginning of a file name.

For example:

> **file_text.xlsx**

What I need it to look like:

> **10-30-2021_file_text.xlsx**

I would like to append to the beginning of the file name, and add my own string(s)

NOTE: 'file_text' are randomly generated file names, and all unique. So I would need to keep the unique names and just add to the beginning of each unique file name.

Here is what I have so far to rename the other files, I figured I could reference a space but this did not work as there are no spaces.

```
import os

directory = os.getcwd()

txt_replaced = ' '
txt_needed = '2021-10-31'

for f in os.listdir(directory):
    os.rename(os.path.join(directory, f),
                os.path.join(directory, f.replace(txt_needed, txt_replaced)))
```

I also am curious if there is a way to reference specific positions within the file name.

For example:

> **text_text1.csv**

If there is a way to uppercase only 'text1'?

Thank you!

Comment: Sidenote: in `f.replace(txt_needed, txt_replaced)`, you have the arguments backwards

Comment: For your additional question, see [How do I convert only specific parts of a string to uppercase in Python?](/q/17794241/4518341), or if you're looking for pattern matching, [Making letters uppercase using re.sub in python?](/q/8934477/4518341)

Comment: I will check out those posts, thank you @wjandrea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace()` doesn't work because there's no space character at the beginning of the filename. So there's nothing to replace.

You also didn't add the `_` character after the date.

Just use ordinary string concatenation or formatting

```
for f in os.listdir(directory):
    os.rename(os.path.join(directory, f),
                os.path.join(directory, f"{txt_needed}_{f}"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a simple fix. I was unaware you can reference the {f} within an f string. Appreciate it.

Comment: Why would `f` be any different from another variable?